# p-button and togglemask not render until clicking input

Tags: angular, button, primeng

I am using `p-button` and `togglemask="true"` from PrimeNG. But they do not render in the html initially until clicked. I want to know why and how to fix this! Thank you!

```html
// user-login.component.html

<main>
    <form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm)">

        <h2>Sign in</h2>        

        <div>
            <span class="p-float-label">
                <input id="username" type="text" pInputText class="p-inputtext-lg"
                [(ngModel)]="username">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
            </span>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <span class="p-float-label">
                <p-password id="password" class="p-inputtext-lg" [toggleMask]="true"
                    [(ngModel)]="password"></p-password>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
            </span>
        </div>

    
        <div>
            <button pButton type="submit" label="Sign in"></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <div>
        <span>New User?</span>
        <button pButton type="button" [routerLink]="'/signup'" label="Create account" class="p-button-text"></button>
    </div>
    
</main>
```

This is the [initial page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo2jX.png) I have without clicking any button in the page.

- The togglemask in password input box is not showing.
- The button is also not showing in desired styling.

```html
// password input without togglemask
<p-password _ngcontent-sqf-c60="" id="password" class="p-element p-inputwrapper p-inputtext-lg"><div><input pinputtext="" class="p-inputtext p-component p-element"><!--container--><!--container--><!--container--></div></p-password>

// button
<button _ngcontent-dxo-c60="" pbutton="" type="submit" label="Sign in" class="p-element" ng-reflect-label="Sign in"></button>
```

Only after clicking the input box, `ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid` added to the `<form>` would the button show with styling, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9lF9.png).

- The togglemask appears but in the wrong position.

```html
// password input with togglemask in wrong position
<p-password _ngcontent-sqf-c60="" id="password" class="p-element p-inputwrapper p-inputtext-lg p-password-mask ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-toggle-mask="true">
    <div ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="">
        <input pinputtext="" class="p-inputtext p-component p-element" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" type="password">
        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><i ng-reflect-ng-class="pi pi-eye" class="pi pi-eye"></i><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
    </div>
</p-password>

// button
<button _ngcontent-ale-c60="" pbutton="" type="submit" label="Sign in" class="p-element p-button p-component" ng-reflect-label="Sign in">
    <span class="p-button-label">Sign in</span>
</button>
```

After clicking the password input box I get the desired styling [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrQRN.png).

```html
// password input with desired togglemask
<p-password _ngcontent-sqf-c60="" id="password" class="p-element p-inputwrapper p-inputtext-lg p-password-mask ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-toggle-mask="true">
    <div ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="p-password p-component p-inputwrapper p-input-icon-right">
        <input pinputtext="" class="p-inputtext p-component p-element p-password-input" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" type="password">
        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><i ng-reflect-ng-class="pi pi-eye" class="pi pi-eye"></i><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
    </div>
</p-password>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error mentioned by [skink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577167/skink), I fixed the problem by simply adding `name` attribute in `<input>` as follow:

```
<input id="username" type="text" pInputText
            [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
```

The reason using `name` attribute is specified in angular doc [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms#naming-control-elements):

> When you use [(ngModel)] on an element, you must define a name attribute for that element. Angular uses the assigned name to register the element with the NgForm directive attached to the parent  element.

and [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control):

> When using the ngModel within  tags, you'll also need to supply a name attribute so that the control can be registered with the parent form under that name.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced the issue on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-demo-4encgi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts), and there seems to be a quite unambiguous error (that you don't see?):

> Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
>
> Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
> Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">

Which is totally right, you're mixing reactive forms with normal forms. If you meant to use normal forms, then the `form` element should be removed from the DOM and the form submission should be handled at the button level:

```html
<!--<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm)">-->

<button pButton type="submit" (onClick)="login()" label="Sign in"></button>

<!--</form>-->
```

If you meant to use reactive forms, the `ngModel` bindings should be replaced with the `formControlName` attributes:

```html
<input
  id="username"
  type="text"
  pInputText
  class="p-inputtext-lg"
  formControlName="username"
/>

<p-password
  id="password"
  class="p-inputtext-lg"
  [toggleMask]="true"
  formControlName="password"
></p-password>
```

Comment: yes I overlooked the error shown in the browser only focusing on angular being compiled successfully :/ I was meant to use a template driven form though. But thanks for pointing out the unambiguous error!